# Why does a semicolon seem to be necessary here?

Tags: javascript, syntax, webpack

Deep in the mines of my Webpack-bundled JS app, I find this code:

```js
var headers = Object.keys(headersObj).map(function (name) {
 return [headersObj[name].name, headersObj[name].value]
})
 
(window).fetch(self._opts.url, // and so on...
```

Which seems to be coming from stream-http as required by (at some depth) the Slack API Node library.

This code, when run, throws this error:

```js
VM481:672 Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys(...).map(...) is not a function
    at module.exports.ClientRequest._onFinish (eval at App (container.js:94), <anonymous>:672:4)
    at module.exports.eval (eval at App (container.js:94), <anonymous>:614:9)
    at module.exports.EventEmitter.emit (eval at App (container.js:94), <anonymous>:3615:18)
    at finishMaybe (eval at App (container.js:94), <anonymous>:4371:15)
    at afterWrite (eval at App (container.js:94), <anonymous>:4253:4)
    at afterTick (eval at App (container.js:94), <anonymous>:4719:11)
    at Item.run (eval at App (container.js:94), <anonymous>:3037:15)
    at drainQueue (eval at App (container.js:94), <anonymous>:3007:43)
```

Which is the same error that occurs if `Object.keys` is run on an undefined variable. However, `headersObj` is defined, and is an object.

When I change the code to:

```js
var headers = Object.keys(headersObj).map(function (name) {
 return [headersObj[name].name, headersObj[name].value]
}); // <- please note yon semicolon
 
(window).fetch(self._opts.url, // and so on...
```

It **works fine**. The problem is, this isn't my code. I can't easily add the semicolon upstream of the bundled script.

1. Why is this semicolon seemingly necessary?
2. What can I do to resolve this without changing the source code?

### Edit

Looks like the issue (pointed out in comments) is that the original code is being interpreted as:

```js
var headers = Object.keys(headersObj).map(function (name) {
 return [headersObj[name].name, headersObj[name].value]
})(window).fetch(self._opts.url, // and so on...
```

which is more clearly a call to the result (which is a list, not a function) passing in `window`.

The instance of `window` is being generated by a Webpack plugin:

```js
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    global: 'window'
  })
],
```

which seems to be implicitly wrapping `window` in parens. Is there a way to change that behavior?

Comment: It seems to be problem with js minification, where those line join `})(window` together without using semi-colon, hence with semi-colon, those two lines are separated `});(window` even after js minification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Why is this semicolon seemingly necessary?**

If you do not add the semicolon, JavaScript will understand that it needs to get the return value of the expression `var headers = Object.keys(headersObj).map(...)` -- which is an array -- and then call it, passing `window` as a parameter. It will throw an error because your array is not a function. It's basically doing something like this:

```
var headers = (Object.keys(headersObj).map(...))(window).fetch(self._opts.url, // and so on...
```

**2. What can I do to resolve this without changing the source code?**

I can't see any way to fix that without changing the source code. You can add the semicolon either at the end of the first line (as you pointed), or at the start of the second line:

```
var headers = Object.keys(headersObj).map(...)

;(window).fetch(self._opts.url, // and so on...
```

The article [Semicolons in JavaScript are optional](http://mislav.net/2010/05/semicolons/) describes the same problem you're facing in the section "The only real pitfall when coding without semicolons".

Answer (score 0):

### Bloated??

This is an odd case as you would not expect to see a single expression wrapped parentheses. `(window)` is the same as `window` the parentheses are superfluous.

The obvious solution is to simply remove the redundant parentheses

```
var headers = Object.keys(headersObj).map(...)

window.fetch(self._opts.url, // and so on...
```

Adding a leading semicolon is just bloating.

#### The immediately invoked anonymous function

There is the case of the immediately invoked anonymous function

```
(function(){... some code }());  // the Crockford way or
(function(){... some code })();
```

Which many times is the opening line of a script file. If such a script file is concatenated into a single file for release it will throw the same error if the line before is without a semicolon and evaluates as an expression.

```
var a = 0       // this line is an expression (it has a value)
(function(){... some code }())  // throws 0 is not a function

if(a !== b){ }  // this line is a statement it does not have a value
(function(){... some code }())  // works
```

If you write public libraries or concat your own library files, when using immediately invoked anonymous functions, and it is the first expression it pays to put a semicolon before the first parentheses to protect from a hanging expression (for want of a better term)

```
var a = 0 // the expression stays in context until terminated
;(function(){... some code }())  // safe as the previous expression is no longer in context.
```

Note also that a immediately invoked anonymous function evaluates as an expression.

```
(function(){... some code }())
(function(){... some code }())  // throws "is not a function error..

(function(){... some code })()  // alternative form
(function(){... some code }())  // throws "is not a function error...
```

It is thus alway good practice to terminate expressions explicitly with the semicolon.

```
// good if guaranteed first line
(function(){... some code }());
(function(){... some code }()); 

// Best
;(function(){... some code }());
(function(){... some code }());
```