# Adding class to multiple elements with querying selector

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to cut down on my verbose `classList.add('lorem')` calls. I can easily add the same class to multiple created elements like so:

```
const loremDiv = document.createElement('div'), ipsumDiv = document.createElement('div')

loremDiv.classList.add('hi')
ipsumDiv.classList.add('hi')
```

But when I try to add the class via a single `forEach` like so:

```
[loremDiv,ipsumDiv].forEach((el) => {
    el.classList.add('hi')
}
```

I get the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')

Comment: There should be no such error given the code you posted.

Comment: I bet you are not terminating the preceding statement with a semicolon and thus `[...]` is interpreted as property access. Use semicolons! Not the same syntax, but the same reason: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41905600/218196

Comment: I guess you are referring to the previous line not having a semicolon? Not sure by your comment. But my code is free of such errors or my linter would have complained.

Comment: @ZachSmith all you have to do is put a semicolon *before* `[loremDiv, ipsumDiv]` to see whether Mr Kling's supposition is correct. Your linter is going to complain about syntax errors, and a missing semicolon in a situation like this is not a *syntax* error, it's a *runtime* error.

Comment: As mentioned, the code is syntactically valid, so a linter wouldn't be able to catch that issue. The linter cannot know that you are not actually trying to access a property but want to create an array literal. I mean, it could technically flag property access that contains a comma operator expression as suspicious. I wonder whether there's an eslint rule/plugin for that.

Comment: Ah, there is a rule to disallow all (non-parenthesized) comma operator uses: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-sequences. Enabling this would alert you that the code is not doing what you intend to do. Found via yet another question about this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69199200/eslint-showing-unexpected-use-of-comma-no-sequences-for-an-array

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you are missing vital semi-colons. Both Felix and Pointy make valid points. There is really no need to omit semi-colons. It may look more hip and modern, but it will bite you down the road and cause cryptic errors like this.

### Fails

The [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) call returns an element, but since you did not include a semi-colon, it runs into the next line like so:

```js
document.createElement('div')[loremDiv, ipsumDiv]
```

Since you did not terminate the `ipsumDiv` assignment, the interpreter is complaining that it was not assigned already.

---

As for the `forEach((el) => el.classList.add('hi'))` call, [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) returns nothing, so you are calling `loremDiv` on an `undefined` object.

```js
forEach((el) => el.classList.add('hi'))[loremDiv, ipsumDiv]
```

```js
const 
  loremDiv = document.createElement('div'),
  ipsumDiv = document.createElement('div') // Missing semi-colon!
  
// "Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ipsumDiv' before initialization"

[loremDiv, ipsumDiv].forEach((el) => el.classList.add('hi')) // Missing semi-colon!

// "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '#<HTMLDivElement>')"

[loremDiv, ipsumDiv].forEach((el) => document.body.append(el)) // Optional semi-colon
```

```css
.hi:before { content: "HI!" }
```

### Working

```js
const 
  loremDiv = document.createElement('div'),
  ipsumDiv = document.createElement('div'); // Semi-colon required
  
[loremDiv, ipsumDiv].forEach((el) => el.classList.add('hi')); // Semi-colon required

[loremDiv, ipsumDiv].forEach((el) => document.body.append(el)); // Why not add one?
```

```css
.hi:before { content: "HI!" }
```